# Is it possible to stream video with pubnub using the ios SDK

Tags: ios, video, video-streaming, pubnub

I've seen some documentation on streaming video using Pubnub, but the examples I've seen have been using the javascript SDK. Is it possible to stream video using the iOS SDK?

Comment: PubNub is not used to stream the video (Web, Mobile or otherwise). Please see this KB article, [Does PubNub Provide WebRTC and Video Chat](https://www.pubnub.com/knowledge-base/discussion/252/does-pubnub-provide-webrtc-and-video-chat#latest), for full details.